# Иерархический (рекурсивный) запрос postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, рекурсия

Есть такая таблица!

[image: friends]

мне надо выбирать друзей друзей пользователя и т.д. с указанием уровня вложенности.

сейчас написал такой запрос

```
WITH RECURSIVE temp1 AS (
SELECT fr1.user1_id, fr1.user2_id, fr1.time_creation, 1 as level 
FROM friends fr1 WHERE fr1.user1_id = 1
union
select fr2.user1_id, fr2.user2_id, fr2.time_creation, level+1 as level
FROM friends fr2 INNER JOIN temp1 ON 
(temp1.user2_id = fr2.user1_id and fr2.user2_id != 1 ) 
where level < 4)
select * from temp1 order by user1_id, level
```

Результат такого запроса

[image: query]

как мне изменить условие `fr2.user2_id != 1` чтоб исключить пользователей для которых друзья найдены?

**UPD**

Изменил запрос на

```
WITH RECURSIVE temp1 AS (
SELECT fr1.user1_id, fr1.user2_id, fr1.time_creation, 1 as level 
FROM friends fr1 WHERE fr1.user1_id = 1
union
select   fr2.user1_id, fr2.user2_id, fr2.time_creation, level+1 as level
FROM friends fr2 INNER JOIN temp1 ON 
(temp1.user2_id = fr2.user1_id and temp1.user2_id != 1 ) 
where level < 10000 )
select distinct user1_id, user2_id, time_creation from temp1 
where user1_id != 1 order by user1_id
```

Не уверен что это лучшее и верное решение

Comment: можно наверное group by сделать а поле level в нее не включать и сделать от него min()

Comment: @Mike по поводу distinct верно ли будет его использовать? ведь я как понимаю будут выбираться все поля и просто исключаться повторяющиеся

Comment: В distinct можно же тоже не включать level. И это работает, но я не уверен что это верно. При большом количестве думаю будет все плохо. Мне просто надо исключать id юзеров для которых уже искал. Я не силён в sql, такое можно реализовать?

Comment: Получается у 1 друга есть друг 2 у друга 2 есть друг 3 у друга 3 есть 4 и когда я дойду до выборки друзей друга 4 мне надо исключить уже 1, 2 и 3 юзера

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Внутри рекурсии можно подавить только циклические связи. например если u1 ссылается на u2 который ссылается на u3, а тот ссылается опять на u1. Если же связь с одним и тем же пользователем идет разными путями, т.е. u1->u2->u3 и u1->u4->u3 то убрать второго u3 внутри самой рекурсии уже нельзя, т.к. при его выборке нельзя сослаться на ранее выбранные записи u2->u3. Вторую часть дублей можно убрать только с помощью group by после отработки рекурсии.

Циклические связи убираются запоминанием всего маршрута как мы добрались до конкретной записи и последующей проверки, что бы вновь выбираемый id не входил в маршрут. Можно из запроса убрать group by и добавить поле path в выборку, что бы увидеть маршруты.

```
WITH RECURSIVE temp1 AS (
  SELECT fr1.user1_id, fr1.user2_id, fr1.time_creation, 1 as level,'/1/' as path 
    FROM friends fr1 WHERE fr1.user1_id = 1
  union
  select fr2.user1_id, fr2.user2_id, fr2.time_creation, level+1 as level,
         temp1.path||fr2.user1_id||'/' path
    FROM friends fr2
   INNER JOIN temp1
      ON (temp1.user2_id = fr2.user1_id and fr2.user2_id != 1
           and temp1.path not like '%/'||fr2.user1_id||'/%') 
   where level < 4
)
select user1_id,user2_id,time_creation,min(level)
  from temp1
 group by user1_id,user2_id,time_creation
 order by user1_id, min(level)
```

Comment: Спасибо! Работает как надо