# PostgreSQL: рекурсивный обход дерева вверх в PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, рекурсия, дерево

есть таблица вида

```
[id] [name] [parent]
```

В поле `parent` указывается `name` родителя.
Если у записи нет родителя, то `parent = name`.

Необходимо зная `id` записи найти всех его детей, а также предков и "племянников", т.е. полностью обойти дерево в обе стороны.

Вот таким запросом:

```
WITH RECURSIVE tmp_t AS (
    -- стартовая часть рекурсии 
    SELECT id, name, parent
    FROM tree_t
    WHERE id = <id записи>

    UNION ALL

    -- рекурсивная часть
    SELECT t.id, t.name, t.parent 
    FROM tree_t AS t
    JOIN tmp_t ON t.parent = tmp_t.name AND t.parent <> t.name
)
SELECT tmp_t.id
FROM tmp_t;
```

я могу найти только все дочерние элементы.

А как найти все элементы от которых можно добраться до указанного `id`?

P.S.

И второй вопрос - а как подняться вверх и найти корень дерева? Т.е. sql запрос должен выдать `id` самого старшего родителя.

Comment: [Иерархические структуры и деревья в SQL](https://www.osp.ru/pcworld/2007/03/4199032). / По термину "список смежности" - "adjacency list" можно найти ещё примеры.

Comment: Если `t.parent = tmp_t.name` заменить на `tmp_t.parent = t.name` то пойдем по дереву в другую сторону. А если объединить OR оба условия, то будем находить и вверх и вниз. Но в таком случае нам надо будет не зациклиться. А для этого можно в списке выборки добавить признак например так же в виде `t.parent = tmp_t.name` и учесть в условиях еще и его, типа что бы продолжать движение только в том же направлении, которое определилось на предыдущем шаге. Ну или сохранять полный пройденный путь, что бы точно ничего второй раз не получить

Comment: Вот тут в двух направлениях ходили https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/944584/194569 А вот тут путь строили и проверяли, что ранее на этой ветви еще не были https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/496807/194569

Comment: @Mike, по поводу зацикливания не понял (оно действительно наблюдается) - Вы предлагаете ввести еще один критерий, который будет показывать алгоритму что скажем вверх уже подыматься не надо с этого узла если узел был найден?

Comment: ну это два разных метода, первый смотрим направление движения и не мешаем их между собой (это по первой ссылке), второй, более универсальный (он по второй ссылке), обратите внимание, там собирается строка path из id уже пройденных узлов вроде /1/5/13 и потом по ней like ищется а встречался ли ранее id который сейчас попадает в выборку и если он уже был, то больше его не используем. Ну и вообще этот path очень удобен для отладки, по нему видно как по дереву шли

Comment: @Mike, первый я понял, т.е. движение вверх и вниз, тут все ок, проверил, замечательно работает, а вот второй пока еще не могу толком осознать, по пытаюсь :(

Comment: все разобрался заработало огромное спасибо!

Comment: @Mike, все работает, все супер, но возникает многократное дублирование в ответе. Не подскажешь в чем может быть дело? Т.е. определяет то все корректно, но смущают многократные дублирования, хотя проверка вроде в запросе стоит не ходить по уже пройденным путям (добавил в ответе код)

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, Вы многократно обходите дерево, составляя список всех возможных путей из данного узла.
Посмотрите пример. Здесь делается различие в движении к родителю (вверх) и потомкам(вниз). От родителей вниз - по "чужим" ветвям - не ходим.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.dbg_get_tree_full(
    node_id bigint)
    RETURNS TABLE(id bigint, name text,parent_id text,lvl int,path text,updown int) 
    LANGUAGE 'sql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE
    ROWS 1000

AS $BODY$
    WITH RECURSIVE tmp_t AS (
        SELECT 1 lvl,t1.name, t1.parent, t1.id, 1 as level
              , '/'||cast(t1.id as varchar)||'/' as path
              ,0 updown
        FROM dbg_tree t1
        WHERE t1.id = node_id

        UNION

        SELECT tmp_t.lvl+1,t2.name, t2.parent, t2.id, level+1 as level
            , tmp_t.path||t2.name||'/' path
            ,case when t2.parent = tmp_t.name AND t2.parent <> t2.name then 1 
                when tmp_t.parent = t2.name AND tmp_t.parent <> tmp_t.name then -1
             end
        FROM dbg_tree t2
        INNER JOIN tmp_t
        ON (
            (
                (t2.parent = tmp_t.name AND t2.parent <> t2.name 
                  and (updown=0 or updown=1)
                 )
             OR 
                (tmp_t.parent = t2.name AND tmp_t.parent <> tmp_t.name
                  and (updown=0 or updown=-1)
                )
            )
            AND tmp_t.path NOT LIKE '%/'||t2.name||'/%') 
    )
    SELECT id, name,parent,lvl,path,updown
    FROM tmp_t
$BODY$;
select * from public.dbg_get_tree_full(2)
order by id
```

Результат запроса

| id | name | parent_id | lvl | path | updown |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | A | 2 | /2/A/ | -1 |
| 2 | AB | A | 1 | /2/ | 0 |
| 6 | ABB | AB | 2 | /2/ABB/ | 1 |
| 7 | ABC | AB | 2 | /2/ABC/ | 1 |
| 8 | ABA | AB | 2 | /2/ABA/ | 1 |
| 11 | ABBA | ABB | 3 | /2/ABB/ABBA/ | 1 |
| 12 | ABCA | ABC | 3 | /2/ABC/ABCA/ | 1 |
| 13 | ABCB | ABC | 3 | /2/ABC/ABCB/ | 1 |
| 14 | ABBAA | ABBA | 4 | /2/ABB/ABBA/ABBAA/ | 1 |
| 15 | ABBAB | ABBA | 4 | /2/ABB/ABBA/ABBAB/ | 1 |

Для узла 11 результат будет такой

| id | name | parent_id | lvl | path | updown |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | A | 4 | /11/ABB/AB/A/ | -1 |
| 2 | AB | A | 3 | /11/ABB/AB/ | -1 |
| 6 | ABB | AB | 2 | /11/ABB/ | -1 |
| 11 | ABBA | ABB | 1 | /11/ | 0 |
| 14 | ABBAA | ABBA | 2 | /11/ABBAA/ | 1 |
| 15 | ABBAB | ABBA | 2 | /11/ABBAB/ | 1 |

Answer (score 0):

Возникла проблема дубликатов. Подскажите в чем может быть дело?

создал такую таблицу

```
id, name, parent
1,A,A
2,AB,A
3,AA,A
4,AAA,AA
5,AAB,AA
6,ABB,AB
7,ABC,AB
8,ABA,AB
9,AAABA,AAB
10,AAABB,AAB
11,ABBA,ABB
12,ABCA,ABC
13,ABCB,ABC
14,ABBAA,ABBA
15,ABBAB,ABBA
16,B,B
17,BA,B
18,BB,B
19,BBA,BB
20,BBB,BB
21,C,C
```

И соответственно код для обхода дерева:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.dbg_get_tree_full(
    node_id bigint)
    RETURNS TABLE(id bigint, parent_id text) 
    LANGUAGE 'sql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE
    ROWS 1000

AS $BODY$
    WITH RECURSIVE tmp_t AS (
        SELECT t1.name, t1.parent, t1.id, 1 as level, '/1/' as path
        FROM dbg_tree t1
        WHERE t1.id = node_id

        UNION

        SELECT t2.name, t2.parent, t2.id, level+1 as level, tmp_t.path||t2.name||'/' path
        FROM dbg_tree t2
        INNER JOIN tmp_t
        ON (
            (
                t2.parent = tmp_t.name AND t2.parent <> t2.name OR 
                tmp_t.parent = t2.name AND tmp_t.parent <> tmp_t.name
            )
            AND tmp_t.path NOT LIKE '%/'||t2.name||'/%') 
    )
    SELECT id, parent
    FROM tmp_t
$BODY$;
```

В результате запроса:

```
select * from dbg_get_tree_full(2)
```

получается 61 запись!!! (Хотя в базе их 21, причем лишь часть образуют дерево)

Если же посмотреть кол-во записей

```
select *
from (
select id, parent_id, COUNT(*) as c
from dbg_get_tree_full(2)
group by id, parent_id) as t
where t.c > 1
```

то можно увидеть многократное дублирование

```
id  parent_id  count
6   "AB"    3
12  "ABC"   3
2   "A" 3
15  "ABBA"  3
13  "ABC"   3
1   "A" 3
8   "AB"    3
4   "AA"    3
11  "ABB"   3
14  "ABBA"  3
9   "AAB"   3
5   "AA"    3
7   "AB"    4
3   "A" 3
10  "AAB"   3
```

подскажите как это исправить можно и в чем дело - почему такое вообще возникло!

Comment: А почему вы написали вопрос в ответе?